# Laravel import is wrong. App runs on my PC but crashes on co-worker's

Tags: php, laravel

On one of the app models there's an import
`App\CustomClasses\Core\Model`
This is wrong as the correct path is `App\CustomClasses\Files\Core\Model`

The issue here is that the app is running fine on my PC and this is something I would not have noticed by myself if my code was not under review. Does Laravel cache import paths somewhere? I can't make any sense of this.

Comment: check in the `config/app.php` if you have an alias for that class

Comment: nope, no alias. The app is also running like that on production, but co-worker had to fix that in order to get the app running on his end

Comment: maybe composer is doing some caching, try to wipe cache and dump autoloads on localhost, and check if it still works with the wrong import

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to run following command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: i've cleared cache multiple times, no luck, i just pulled the fix and let this go on as a mistery

Comment: oh, usually these kinds of issues happen due to cache configurations most of the time!